# Which CodeIgniter Template Library fits requirements?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, template-engine

I would like to use tags like {{headline}} in the CodeIgniter views instead of PHP and I'm looking for a template parser. CodeIgniter has a built-in template parser: http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html

The question is if it's better to use the built-in parser or another parser? Are there any limitations with the CI template parser like not supporting loops, if statements, etc.?

If so, there are a number of other parsers but it seems that a developer works on them for some time and then it falls into a numb state when it's not supported any more. I'm looking for a parser which will also be supported in a year:

Bucket
http://backstack.ca/projects/bucket/

Comper Template Parser
http://parser.comper.sk/en/

Ocular-Template-Library
http://github.com/lonnieezell/Ocular-Template-Library

Phil Sturgeon Template library
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template

PyroCMS Lex Parser
http://github.com/pyrocms/lex

Template Library for CodeIgniter
http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/

The most active seem to be Comper and Lex Parser. What is the difference between Phil Sturgeon Template library and PyroCMS Lex Parser because it's the same developer?

What I am looking for is:
- Separation of PHP and HTML/CSS in views
- Solidly supported so that it's not stalled within a year
- Use of simple tags but also loops, if statements and other functions

Can anyone give me a tip? The existing information on the CI forum or elsewhere have not been really useful.

Many thanks!

Philip

Comment: Williams Concepts' library is great, but it is really a Layout Manager, not a parser - it supports the use of other parsers. I WOULD get into the habit of using these; much easier for larger projects

Answer (score 0):

### How to Choose a Template Engine

I went through a similar exercise for choosing a PHP/CMS system, and here are some points that may carry over to your decision making process.

1. I first look at the documentation to get a sense of how much support there is for the system, evaluate range of features and so on.  I also see if there is an online forum with enough activity to get some help if needed.
2. I then try out the installation to see if it goes smoothly.  If I have trouble at this stage, I may simply quit and try another system unless there is an online forum or help desk with a ready answer.
3. I then set up a sample website (2-3 pages) and try out the features that I need.  In the case of CodeIgniter, I may have content stored in multiple database tables and I evaluate how much effort it takes to get the data from my SQL queries into the array structure that can be used by the template system.  This is usually the step that takes the most effort when developing the website.
4. I also check to see how easy I could integrate a PHP function into the mix.  For example, I once had to build a specialized function to determine a range of dates and these dates had to be passed to the template engine.  I was able to do it but it took a lot of effort.  The template system had almost no support for parsing dates and I had to resort to a PHP function to do the work.

**Summary**

Ultimately, you will need to try a few of these systems out to get a feel for them.  Once that is done, pick one that makes sense for your coding style, ease of use, and your data structure.

**PS**

I have not used the systems that you listed above but I have spent quite a bit of time using the template engine in Expression Engine (CMS from the same group that created CodeIgniter).  My comments are based on my experience implementing database driven websites using Expression Engine and dealing with the limitations and quirks of that particular platform.

Comment: Well, it's your personal opinion. I already decided to implement a template engine but I don't know which. Any feedback regarding how to choose the right one is welcome.

Comment: I reread your question and rewrote my answer with some pointers that may be of help.